# AWS SAM VSCode ptvsd debugging not using breakpoints

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, serverless-application-model

I'm trying to follow the instructions I found here for debugging a Python SAM application in VS Code

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging-python.html

I'm not sure why they don't use `sam build` in the expamle, and point to `.aws-sam/build` but that's what I'm attempting.

My `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [        
        {
            "name": "SAM CLI Python debug test",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5890,
            "host": "localhost",
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/.aws-sam/build",
                    "remoteRoot": "/var/task"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm triggering the Lambda's directly for now and so I'm invoking them like this:

```
sam local invoke -d 5890
```

I'm then putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the Lambda I find in the `build` folder, but when I start the debugger in VS Code it executes the Lambda without stopping at the breakpoint.

I created a GitHub repo with the test project I'm using and description of how I'm using it.

https://github.com/rupe120/aws-sam-python-debugging-test

Could someone help point me at what I'm missing in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

So, the recommended way to do this is with the AWS Toolkit extension.

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/issues/1926#issuecomment-616600799

Answer (score 0):

So the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging-python.html) suggest using a `localRoot` of `"${workspaceFolder}/hello_world/build"` (assuming one is using the Hello World template). However, it only works when removing the `build` at the end of the path:

```
"localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/hello_world"
```

This way, I got it to work without the AWS Toolkit.